# Add media dynamically on gutenberg block

Tags: block-editor

I want to make a carousel gallery with WordPress Gutenberg but I'm facing an dilemma. How do I add images dynamically?

I could go and add like 10 MediaUpload but this isn't very reliable.

I'm thinking about a button that might create MediaUpload

```
el(MediaUpload, {
    onSelect: onSelectInfoImage,
    type: 'image',
    value: attributes.smallMediaURL,
    render: function (obj) {
      return el(components.Button, {
        className: attributes.smallMediaID ? 'image-button' : 'button button-large',
        onClick: obj.open
      },
      !attributes.smallMediaID ? i18n.__('Bild hochladen') : el('img', { src: attributes.smallMediaURL })
      )
    }
})
```

and the button should be something like

```
el(IconButton,{
    className: 'media-create',
    icon: 'no',
    label: 'Add slide',
    onClick: function (media) {
        ***spawn new media***
      }
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set the `multiple` and `gallery` props to `{true}` which enables to select multiple images and make a gallery. More information in the GitHub readme:
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/media-upload